# Paging system for Magento / Wordpress Blogs

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

I'm trying to create a paging system where Magento grabs the WordPress blogs, but I've only come across `$this->getPosts();` which grabs every post in a category.

I have Magento installed along with FishPig/WordPress. I've come to realize you cannot call any WordPress functions, so how would I go about creating a paging system for WordPress blogs inside Magento?

I'd just like to state that I'm new to Magento.

Comment: Good question!  I too am interested in this.  I know you can contact the developers at FishPig directly, and they're willing to help out, though I think they do charge.

Comment: Are you talking about fishpig magento-wordpress integration module http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration.html ?